# Kivy RecycleView. How to refresh the screen after deleting data

Tags: python, kivy

What i'm trying to do is find a way to refresh a table made by using recycleview,

If you press one of the label created, my code delete data from table, but not refresh the table on a graphic level

Obviously if you press the same label 2 times, python gives ValueError...

Here's my code:
temp.py

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty
from kivy.properties import ListProperty

class Sfondo_tabella(RecycleDataViewBehavior, Label):
    index = None
    selected = BooleanProperty(False)
    selectable = BooleanProperty(True)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and self.selectable:
            x = Screen_1()
            x.remove(self.text)

class Screen_1(Screen):
    data_items = ListProperty([])
    data_items = ['1', '2', '3']

    def remove(self, data):
        self.data_items.remove(data)

class TempApp(App):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TempApp().run()
```

temp.kv

```
ScreenManager:
    id: screen_manager
    name: "screen_manager"

    Screen_1:
        id: screen_1
        name: "Screen_1"
        manager: screen_manager

<Sfondo_tabella>:
    # Draw a background to indicate selection
    color: 0,0,0,1
    font_size:  self.height * 0.5
    text_size: self.width, None
    valign: 'top'
    halign: 'center'

    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (1, 1, 1, 1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba:0,0,0,1
        Line:
            width:0.5
            rectangle:(self.x,self.y,self.width,self.height)


<Screen_1>:

    BoxLayout:
        RecycleView:
            viewclass: 'Sfondo_tabella'
            data: [{'text': str(x)} for x in root.data_items]
            RecycleGridLayout:
                cols: 10
                size_hint: 1, None
                default_size: None, dp(20)
                default_size_hint: 1, None
                height: self.minimum_height
                width: self.minimum_width
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are not updating the `RecycleView` data. The `refresh_view_attrs` function should be overloaded to get the `index` of the label clicked/touched upon and then the data needs to be updated accordingly. Following is the updated code for `temp.py`:

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty
from kivy.properties import ListProperty

class Sfondo_tabella(RecycleDataViewBehavior, Label):
    index = None
    selected = BooleanProperty(False)
    selectable = BooleanProperty(True)

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        self.index = index
        return super(Sfondo_tabella, self).refresh_view_attrs(rv, index, data)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and self.selectable:
            x = Screen_1()
            x.remove(self.text)
            self.parent.parent.data.pop(self.index)

class Screen_1(Screen):
    data_items = ListProperty([])
    data_items = ['1', '2', '3']

    def remove(self, data):
        self.data_items.remove(data)

class TempApp(App):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TempApp().run()
```

This will update properly the data of `RecycleView` and the GUI accordingly.

Comment: You know the way to completely refresh table (like cancel the existing one and recreate another table from zero)?

Assuming the 'remove' function in the class Screen_1, completely change the data_items list


'''
class Screen_1(Screen):

    data_items = ['1', '2', '3']

    def remove(self):
        self.data_items = ['b', 'b', 'b']
'''

Comment: I mean just refresh all the table, if data change

Comment: One way to do this is to pass the recycleview class ```self.parent.parent``` as parameter of ```remove``` function from ```on_touch_down``` event in ```Sfondo_tabella``` class. While define the ```remove``` function like ```def remove(self, rv): for x in range(len(self.data_items)): rv.data[x]['text'] = 'b'    rv.refresh_from_data()```. This will refresh the whole table with the text 'b' for each elelment.